# How to represent a json with keys and values in neural embedding if you don't have unique indices using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create a recommendation algorithm and for that I generate embeds for each representation of user actions + product.
But I have a problem, when I have a json with keys and values ​​that represent the values ​​of a product, I don't really know how to represent it in embedding using pytorch.
For example I can have a json like

```
[{color: red}]
```

How could I represent it? I saw the version where the key has an index and the value an index, but I cannot save these unique indices somewhere. How else could I represent?